# HotModuleReload plugin gives type error when added to config

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

I have added HMR plugin as shown here: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hot-module-replacement-plugin/

But I get this error:

> [webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/project/webpack.config.js'

> [webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin is not a constructor

Here is my config:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const { webpack } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9900
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

What did I do wrong?